# alignment box for inline-block non-replaced elements

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Please run the demo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.body {
  font-family: Microsoft Yahei;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 2;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.body span {
  background-color: pink;
}

.body .inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;
}

.inline-block.text {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <span>
words-g words words-g
  <span class="inline-block text">with inline-block box child</span> words-g w
  </span>
</div>
```

The point is that I set

```
.inline-block.text {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

According to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#leading):

> In the following definitions, for inline non-replaced elements, **the box used for alignment is the box whose height is the 'line-height'** (containing the box's glyphs and the half-leading on each side, see above). For all other elements, the box used for alignment is the margin box.

and in the section 'line-height':

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element. The minimum height consists of a minimum height above the baseline and a minimum depth below it, exactly as if each line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the element's font and line height properties. We call that imaginary box a "strut." (The name is inspired by TeX.).

So,in this case,`.inline-block.text`is a

- block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements
- whose height is 50px and line-height is 32px
- also is an inline non-replaced elements

And here is my question:

> **the box used for alignment is the box whose height is the 'line-height'**

1. **What is the above box point at in this case for `.inline-block.text`?**

As the demo shows,I think it is the box with height 50px. However,the box's height is not the line-height which conflicts with the specification above. So,I was confused and don't understand the above sentence in the specification.

2. **And if you think the above box is the box with height 50px,how do you explain the fact that  height 50px is not the line-height 32px?**

Please notice:

- I just want to understand this sentence which is **the box used for alignment is the box whose height is the 'line-height'**,so I can understand the vertical-align better.
- I am not asking for a specific solution.

Whatever thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> for inline non-replaced elements, the box used for alignment is the box whose height is the 'line-height'

does not apply to inline-blocks. Inline-blocks are not inline elements. Inline elements are elements with `display: inline`, and generate inline boxes. Inline-blocks are not inline boxes, but *inline-level* (the "-level" part is important!) *block container boxes*. Therefore, the statement

> For all other elements, the box used for alignment is the margin box.

applies instead, which results in `vertical-align: text-top` causing the top outer edge of the inline-block to align with the top of the line box.

Any part of the specification that is said to apply to inline elements does not apply to inline-blocks.

Comment: I was hoping you are right because that will make a lot of questions clear.However,I didn't find any definition of `inline element`.So,where did you find this:`Inline elements are elements with display: inline, and generate inline boxes.`?

Comment: @xianshenglu: In the prose for line-height, in the sentence "On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.", the word "inline" links to section 9.2.2. Section 9 uses "inline element" and "inline box" interchangeably, except that the difference between an element and a box is that an element may generate one or more boxes, which is a separate topic altogether.

Comment: Feels like  a word game. I hate it ! I will check and try to find a definition in the specification or something like that. Anyway,thanks for your help. It may take me a few time  to finish this question.

Comment: @xianshenglu: Yeah, I agree that the spec needs to be a little more consistent in its word usage.

Comment: According to [box-tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#css-box-tree). Maybe we can think like that inline box is corresponding with inline element and inline-level box is corresponding with inline-level element . Agree?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confusing about the reference of the alignment (it aligns relatively to what?).

I will try to explain this with easy words. When using `vertical-align` with an element `a` you align it relatively to its parent element `b` **whataver is the height** of `a` (`b` is the reference). Using correct words it's like this:

> The vertical-align property can be used in two contexts:
>
> To vertically align an **inline element's box** inside its **containing line**
>   **box**. For example, it could be used to vertically position an `<img>` in
>   a line of text.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)</sup>

So the `a` element is the **inline element's box** and the `b` element is the **containing line box** and the height of `b` is defined by it's **line-height** as you already read in the specification.

---

Now let's consider your code and add properties step by step.

Initially let's remove the `inline-block`

```css
.body {
  font-family: Microsoft Yahei;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.body span {
  background-color: pink;
}

.body .inline-block {
  background: orange;
}

.inline-block.text {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <span>
words-g 
  <span class="inline-block text">inline-block</span> words-g w
  </span>
</div>
```

As you can see the inner span has the same `height`/`line-height` as the outer span and both are using the same `font-family`. So logically we see nothing when using `text-top` as vertical alignment.

Now let's add `line-height:2` to the container:

```css
.body {
  font-family: Microsoft Yahei;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  line-height:2;
}

.body span {
  background-color: pink;
}

.body .inline-block {
  background: orange;
}

.inline-block.text {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <span>
words-g 
  <span class="inline-block text">inline-block</span> words-g w
  </span>
</div>
```

In this situation, both span will inherit the `line-height:2` thus the computed value will be `32px` (`2 * font-size`) and this will make the top reference **different** from text-top. To remind about this, here is a figure I shared with your before<sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952703/8620333)</sup>:

[image: Location of the baseline on text]

And if we read the definition about the value `text-top` of `vertical-align`:

> Aligns the **top of the element** with the top of **the parent element's**
>   **font.**

So the top of the inner span will align with the text-top of the outer span, that's why it moved to the bottom. Then the height of the main container `.body` will not be equal to `32px` but it will be bigger because it will consider the movement of inner span (we will have `37px`).

---

Now let's add `inline-block` to the inner element:

```css
.body {
  font-family: Microsoft Yahei;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  line-height:2;
}

.body span {
  background-color: pink;
}

.body .inline-block {
  background: orange;
}

.inline-block.text {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <span>
words-g 
  <span class="inline-block text">inline-block</span> words-g w
  </span>
</div>
```

The first thing you will notice is that the text didn't move BUT the orange background is covering a bigger height. This is because our element will behave as block container and this height is the `line-height` of the text (`32px`) which is also the distance between the top and bottom in the image above (Initially it was covering from `text-bottom` to `text-top`).

It's also like the blue background of the `.body` element since this one is a block element. *Try to make the `.body` element `inline` and see what will happen.*

Now you can also add a specific `height` to the element and nothing will change because we align relatively to **the parent element**. You can also play with all the vaues of `vertical-align` to see the different behaviors:

```css
.body {
  font-family: Microsoft Yahei;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  line-height:2;
  margin:5px;
}

.body span {
  background-color: pink;
}

.body .inline-block {
  background: orange;
}

.inline-block.text {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <span>
Align the 
  <span class="inline-block text" style="
  vertical-align: text-top;">top of this</span> with text-top
  </span>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <span>
Align the 
  <span class="inline-block text" style="
  vertical-align: top;">top of this</span> with top
  </span>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <span>
align the 
  <span class="inline-block text" style="
  vertical-align: text-bottom;">bottom of this</span> with text-bottom
  </span>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <span>
align the 
  <span class="inline-block text" style="
  vertical-align: bottom;">bottom of this</span> with bottom
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think you miss the point I was asking. You can see the another answer which is what I want. However, he didn't find the specific definition. And I am asking css working group for the definition of `inline-element` right now.